# send post request with xml response using ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, http, post, httprequest, payment-gateway

I'm trying to customize the interface provider qiwi
this is my code:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('w.qiwi.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
body = {
  :bill_id => "BILL-#{payment.id}",
  :user => 'tel:' + params[:qiwi][:phone],
  :amount => payment.amount,
  :ccy => 'RUB',
  :comment => "",
  :prv_name => 'Company'
}.to_param
key = "Basic " + Base64.encode64s("secret_key")
http.send_request('POST', "/qiwi-notify.php HTTP/1.1", body, {'Accept' => application/xml', 'Authorization' => key})
```

I need to do the following:

```
POST /qiwi-notify.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic MjA0Mjp0ZXN0Cg==
bill_id=BILL-
1&status=paid&error=0&amount=1.00&user=tel%3A%2B79031811737&prv_nam
e=TEST&ccy=RUB&comment=test&command=bill
Response should XML-doc:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> <result><result_code>0</result_code></result>
```

**how can I implement a request privednny below, my code does not work**
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem then? The code above is not working? Any specific errors, what it produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explicitly state what your problem is, but looking at the code there are a few problems before it can be even interpreted.

```
:bill_id => "BILL-#{payment.id}"
```

needs a `,` at the end.

```
http.send_request('POST', "/qiwi-notify.php HTTP/1.1", body, {'Accept' => application/xml', 'Authorization' => key})
```

is lacking an apostrophe before `application/xml'`.

With those fixes in place, the code ends up looking like

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('w.qiwi.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
body = {
  :bill_id => "BILL-#{payment.id}",
  :user => 'tel:' + params[:qiwi][:phone],
  :amount => payment.amount,
  :ccy => 'RUB',
  :comment => "",
  :prv_name => 'Company'
}.to_param
key = "Basic " + Base64.encode64s("secret_key")
http.send_request('POST', "/qiwi-notify.php HTTP/1.1", body, {'Accept' => 'application/xml', 'Authorization' => key})
```

Comment: Would you give me a good book name,which explains this library of Ruby well..Only looking at the documentation I was not able to understand how this API works?